# Saving ScrollView position

Tags: java, android

I've found the solution for this problem, but it doesn't work quite well. It will restore some position but not exactly. If put some headline at the top, on rotation it won't be the same title on top but it won't put it back at the top too. I have different portrait and landscape UI, so I used this code

```
@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    outState.putIntArray(SCROLL_STATE_KEY, new int[]{mScrollView.getScrollX(),
            mScrollView.getScrollY()});
}

@Override
protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    final int[] scrollPosition = savedInstanceState.getIntArray(SCROLL_STATE_KEY);
    if(scrollPosition != null) {
        mScrollView.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                mScrollView.scrollTo(scrollPosition[0], scrollPosition[1]);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Here's the gif. It is too fast but, I can't put more than 2MB here, so , hope you can see what's not working properly

[image: scrollGif]

Answer (score 0):

Not the solution as sourcecode but an idea how to do this userfriendly:

Before rotation I would get the (text) content of the first visible few words/images of the scrollview and try to scroll the scrollview so that these words/images are on top of the scrollview again after the rotation.

I hav-nt done this for floating text yet but successfully for listviews and grids.

Comment: yeah, but it should normally, probably I missed something somewhere, will give it a try, but as it is for review I think I need to do it like this :)

Comment: the implementatino hightly depends on what is inside the scrollview. probably some kind of webview. if you add this to your question and it-s tags it is much more likely to get a more specific  answer.

Comment: whole activity is in scrollView... in the activity there is data,  except labels, which I get through API key using JSON ...